# How to include prompt text in multiple places in select field with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to insert text that prompts users in my select field? i.e. my dropdown for the select might look like

Select your league

NFL

NHL

NBA

MLB

Alternate leagues

EPL

La Liga

Russian PL

Is this possible in Rails 3.2 I have this code which pulls my primary choices + secondary choices... I would like a prompt before the secondary choices.

```
f.select("league_id", @leagues.collect {|league| [ league.name, league.id ] } + [nil] + @worldwide_leagues.collect {|league| [ league.name, league.id ] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:prompt => true`:

```
f.select("league_id", @leagues.collect {|league| [ league.name, league.id ] } + [nil] + @worldwide_leagues.collect {|league| [ league.name, league.id ] }, :prompt => true)
```

You can also use like this `:prompt => 'please take an option'` if you you want a custom text.

Going even further, if you want to make sure your user will take one choice, add a presence validation on your model.

edit:

Based on your comment, I think what you are looking for are grouped options. Try this:

```
grouped_options = {'Leagues' => @leagues.collect {|league| [ league.name, league.id ] }, 'Alternate Leagues' => @worldwide_leagues.collect {|league| [ league.name, league.id ] } }

f.select(:league_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options), :prompt => 'Select your league' )
```

Comment: Where the [nil] is I want there to be a prompt.... Like the list I have above. What you describe will put the prompt at the top of the list. I need multiple prompts.